# Problem with Deployment an ionic app on vhosting

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, deployment, hosting

I'm trying to solve some deployment problems on vhosting. I used to host an ionic-react website with node server on port 8080.
They closed that port for safety (as they said) and when I asked which other port can i use, they answered to me that I should do a redirect without port, because in the index.html i had a redirect to the website running with node server.
What can I do ?

I was wondering to change the port at the beginning but I don't know where a should change the port.

Comment: [Update]: the hosting provider, closed all the ports, and suggested to change the way of redirect the site and said that for node make it execute on different port has no need because it uses mod_passenger. But i honestly don't know what it means, someone has an answer ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The fact is that it's not a code problem, I can provide the command that I give to the server to start the npm. I used cronjobs to automatize the process because at night the hosting provider does some maintenance stuff.

Comment: forever start $(which npx) serve -l 8080 -s *folder*--ssl-cert *ssl_key*